# MvcSiteMapProvider MVC4 Nuget installation failure Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Installation of MvcSiteMapProvider MVC4 fails when trying to install using Visual Studio 2013 Express edition.
It installs fine in Visual Studio 2012.

The error message I'm getting is: 
Error: "Updating Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.0.0 to Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2.0.3

My quess is that Visual Studio 2013 will not allow Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.0.0 to be overwritten by Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2.0

Has anyone else had issues with MvcSiteMapProvider using VS 2013?

Comment: Did you install the MVC5 version? Visual Studio 2013 ships with MVC5 out of the box.

Comment: I did not install MVC5 directly, I installed VS2013 which has MVC5.

Answer (score 0):

The original package for the MVCSitemapProvider has been marked as obsolete.

To Install the MvcSiteMapProvider, run the following command in the Package Manager Console.

install-package mvcsitemapprovider.mvc[X]

the [X] is what Mvc framework your targeting Ie MVC5 would be: install-package mvcsitemapprovider.mvc5.